Android shared element animation "z-index"
I am working on an album project where I use shared element animations, but I have some confusion. My shared elements seem to affect the hierarchy in the new Activity.
The elements in RelativeLayout will actually have a Fade() animation, but it seems
that they will be executed at a lower level under the shared element animation.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/preview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/operation_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
                app:menu="@menu/preview_toolbar_operation"
                app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_outline_arrow_back"
                app:navigationIconTint="@color/md_theme_onSurfaceVariant" />
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
            app:menu="@menu/preview_bottom_operation" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

